# Building up Java Web Application with JPA for Wildfly fails?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jpa, wildfly

I am trying to build up a Java (Java version build 1.8.0_11-b12) Maven Web Application (built up in NetBeans 8.0) that runs on Wildfly-8.1.0.Final using JPA (EclipseLink JPA 2.1) for accessing a MySQL database. The host system is Ubuntu 14.04 64Bit.

I have successfully created the datasource on Wildfly to the database on MySQL. Testing the connection sends back a message saying it was successful. Therefore, I think Wildfly should be working fine.

I then created a very simple Entity Class "Dog.java" for persisting.

The problem comes up when I compile the WAR file and copy it for deployement on the Wildfly server. Wildfly sends back endless yellow warning messages and I am not able to kill Wildfly or Java. The only way out is to restart the entire operating system.

Does anyone know this problem? Or das anyone see any problem in my configuration?
Does maybe anyone know a Howto somewhere on the net that explains Step-by-Step how to create a Web Application for Wildfly accessing a database with JPA? I already tried to find one, but was not successful.

Every help highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [WildFly Quickstarts](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart).